# Objective-C: Annoying - I get about 5-6 Notifications per minute from my UILocalNotifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

How to fix this issue?
This is my code:

```
NSDate *dateToSet = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0];
NSString *message = @"Test notification";
UILocalNotification *warningNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
warningNotification.fireDate = dateToSet;
warningNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
warningNotification.alertBody = message;
warningNotification.hasAction = NO;
warningNotification.userInfo = nil;
warningNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
warningNotification.soundName = nil;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:warningNotification];
```

And my AppDelegate.m (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

[image]

Comment: What is this line doing: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];`?

Comment: Actually I'm new to UILocalNotifications, this is my first time I'm using it for my new app, i added these codes from tutorials in internet (not by my self).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are configuration your notification to be fired one second in the future, with this line:

> NSDate *dateToSet = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0];

And, setting the interval to `NSCalendarUnitDay` configures it to fire again in one day. Instead, if you want to set notification for the next day, try this:

```
//Present the local notification at the specified time in the future
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

//Next day
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComps.day = 1;

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *futureDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:dateComps toDate:today options:0];

notification.fireDate = futureDate;
```

The line below retrieves all scheduled local notifications, but you don't assign the array to any variable.

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

If you really need an array of local notifications, then try this:

```
NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it won't work! what's this line? notificationDate = futureDate; and also I set the fireDate to my notification to your futureDate, is it correct? warningNotification.fireDate = futureDate;

Comment: Where should i use this array? (localNotification), because it says, unused variable.

Comment: @AlandKawa I updated the answer to assign the future date to the notification. Regarding your question about the localNotifications array, I threw that in there to correct your line of code that didn't assign to an array. If you don't need that line, you can simply remove it.

Comment: I used your code in viewDidLoad method, and this if ([clockString isEqual:@"01:46"]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:_warningNotification];
        }....... but it's not working :/ (The clockString is working for changing labels but it won't receive notifications...

Comment: @AlandKawa I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `clockString`, but you don't need to check for a time before you schedule a notification, unless you want a notification to be fired immediately, in which case, you would set the `fireDate` to `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

It may happen if the object nil object is passing as parameter of method addObserver:selector:name:object:, then it can receive notification from all system which are undesired.

Comment: This is a local notification which notifies the user by NSDate, how can i add that? step by step please...